# SPFx - How to load jsom dependencies in a proper way

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I am getting crazy trying to load scripts like `Runtime.js` and `SP.js`. In the beginning I added the dependencies in the *config.json* as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom). As usual, the Microsoft documentation is buggy and you have to be a wizard to fix the errors.

Anyway, I ended up to [load the SharePoint JSOM scripts with the SPComponentLoader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom#load-the-sharepoint-jsom-scripts-with-the-spcomponentloader). In the debug it works, once deployed without **-p**, I get:

```
SP.Runtime.js:2 Uncaught Error: SP.Runtime.js is already loaded
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Boolean (<anonymous>)
    at SupplementDefaultMethod.window.<computed> [as OriginalOnError] (init.js:1:180299)
    at ULSSendExceptionImpl (init.js:1:106758)
    at ULSOnError (init.js:1:106829)
    at SupplementDefaultMethod.window.<computed> [as OriginalOnError] (init.js:1:180335)
    at ULSSendExceptionImpl (init.js:1:106758)
    at ULSOnError (init.js:1:106829)
    at SupplementDefaultMethod.window.<computed> [as OriginalOnError] (init.js:1:180335)
    at ULSSendExceptionImpl (init.js:1:106758)
    at ULSOnError (init.js:1:106829)
```

If I package the solution with **-p** I get:

```
GET https://relative-path.invalid/sp-init.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
GET https://relative-path.invalid/sp-runtime.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
GET https://relative-path.invalid/sharepoint.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
GET https://relative-path.invalid/microsoft-ajax.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

How do I import these files in order to work in all three scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had a situation where I needed to use the MS Project Server client scripts (PS.js), which depend on the default SharePoint client scripts. I tried the declarative way in the `config.json`, which you link to with your first link, and that didn't work for me, so I also turned to using the `SPComponentLoader`.

And, as you mention, when I was doing the development work in `workbench.aspx` it worked, but once in production, it ran into errors. (I don't remember if I ran into the exact same errors you are reporting, but my guess is that I probably did, based on the solution I came up with, see the code below.)

Keep in mind - I am stuck on SP 2016 on-prem. I'm using SPFx 1.1, and doing development on the hosted `workbench.aspx`. So the following code works for that setup, you may need to adjust for your own setup/working environment.

In any case, this is in my main webpart component (i.e. the main file that gets scaffolded into the `/components/` folder):

```
private componentDidMount = (): void => {
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx') > -1) {
        // if we are doing development work in the workbench,
        // we need to load all of the default sharepoint client scripts
        SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/init.js', {
            globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
        })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
            return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
                globalExportsName: 'Sys'
            });
        })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
            return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
                globalExportsName: 'SP'
            });
        })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
            return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
                globalExportsName: 'SP'
            });
        })
        .then((): Promise<{}> => {
            return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/PS.js', {
                globalExportsName: 'PS'
            });
        })
        .then((): void => {
            this.loadMyData();
        });
    } else {
        // if we are NOT doing development work in the workbench,
        // we only need to load the Project Server client scripts,
        // as all the default sharepoint client scripts will already be loaded
        SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/PS.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'PS'
        })
        .then((): void => {
            this.loadMyData();
        });
    }
}
```

Again, I totally abandoned the `config.js` and just went with this alone.

Comment: Hi, I already thought about this solution, but you agree that is not a clean solution...right?

Comment: It may not be the prettiest solution, no, but - it works. At the end of the day that's really what matters.  And especially with SharePoint, sometimes you just have to find a way that works, no matter what that is.